Flutter app duplicates in recent apps list when opened via push notification
Could someone please help me?
My app duplicates in the recent apps list when I open it via a push notification. Here’s what happens:

I open the app and then close it by pressing the back button.
When I receive a push notification and open the app through the notification, it appears twice in the recent apps list.
However, if I close the app by pressing the home button after the first start, it works normally.

I’ve tried using standard, singleTop, singleTask, and singleInstance launch modes, but none of them solved the issue.
Any advice on how to prevent this duplication in Flutter?
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:label="Жеке Кабинет Дордой"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>

I tried using different launch modes in AndroidManifest.xml, including standard, singleTop, singleTask, and singleInstance. However, none of these modes prevented the app from appearing twice in the recent apps list after being reopened through a push notification.
I expected the app to appear only once in the recent apps list, regardless of how it was reopened, whether through a push notification or directly from the home screen. Specifically, I expected that setting an appropriate launch mode would ensure that the app resumes the existing instance rather than creating a duplicate.

did you verify the package name all around the app and and app name also .

i didnt change the package name from beginning

You may have to check or change the code that launches the activity when the notification is tapped (Android code, not Flutter code), as the Intent flags used to launch override the manifest settings.

in MainActivity.kt?
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    if (!isTaskRoot && intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && intent.action == Intent.ACTION_MAIN) {
        finish()
        return
    }
}

override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    setIntent(intent)
    println("New intent received")
}

}
I did so but it doesnt work
